# How to handle collision detection with different 2D shapes while maintaining performance? Is polymorphism appropriate?

Tags: c++, performance, oop, polymorphism

If I'm making a small library for handling 2D shapes, should polymorphism generally be avoided? I know that it can worsen performance but it's not like polymorphism is never used in game development so I'm unsure of where it actually isn't appropriate.

If we assume we have quite many shapes that all need constant collision detection and similar, how detrimental will polymorphism be to performance? I ask because it's tempting to have an abstract `Shape` that concrete child classes like `Polygon` and `Circle` could inherit from, allowing me to iterate over and handle different kinds of shapes quite smoothly. But will calling purely virtual functions of `Shape` many many times cause performance hits? I'm not too familiar with exactly how polymorphism can affect performance.

Comment: [We have some past Q&A about polymorphic approaches to collision detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=collision+polymorphism+) that may have useful tips for you.

Comment: I feel like you are getting into the trap of premature optimisation. Calling a virtual function versus calling a non-virtual function shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact. Make something that works, regardless if it uses polymorphism or not, and if, later on, your profiling shows that part of the code to be impacting performance, you can re-visit it and optimise it as needed.